# how to use MDB2

Tags: php, mysql, mdb2

I am trying to use `MDB2.php`. I have downloaded XAMPP with the PHP 5.4 version. I understand that, in order to use MDB2, I need to `include` it in my PHP file. This is how I am doing it:

My `createTable.php` file its in `C:\Users\Lexy Feito\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\php\COPassig3`.

So I use the code:

```
require "../../../php/pear/MDB2.php";
```

to include the MDB2.php file located in `C:\Users\Lexy Feito\Desktop\xampp\php\pear` however this is returning the following errors:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in                 C:\Users\Lexy
>   Feito\Desktop\xampp\php\pear\MDB2.php on line 390
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in                                    C:\Users\Lexy
>   Feito\Desktop\xampp\php\pear\MDB2.php on line 1885   Deprecated:
>   Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in
>   C:\Users\Lexy Feito\Desktop\xampp\php\pear\MDB2.php on line 2572
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\Users\Lexy Feito\Desktop\xampp\php\pear\MDB2.php on
>   line 2595
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\Users\Lexy Feito\Desktop\xampp\php\pear\MDB2.php on
>   line 2940
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of MDB2_Driver_Common::raiseError()
>   should be compatible with & PEAR::raiseError($message = NULL, $code =
>   NULL, $mode = NULL, $options = NULL, $userinfo = NULL, $error_class =
>   NULL, $skipmsg = false) in C:\Users\Lexy
>   Feito\Desktop\xampp\php\pear\MDB2.php on line 990

Could somebody tell me what is the correct way of using `MDB2.php` to connect to MySQL and why I'm getting this errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at those "errors", you will see that they are actually just warnings about old-fashioned ("deprecated" means "discouraged and planned for removal in some future version") or badly-written ("strict standards" just means "could be improved") code in the library.

The code will carry on running just fine. *However*, if this library is not currently maintained, you may find that in future you have to either make major changes to it yourself, or move away to a more modern library.

Check out [the `error_reporting` ini setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [`error_reporting()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for how to change which types of messages are displayed or logged.

Comment: "The code will carry on running just fine."... But for how long??? As you said this kind of coding is "discouraged and planned for removal in some future version"...

Comment: @inemanja Well, yes, but this is 3rd-party code, so right now the answer to "what is the correct way of using MDB2.php" is to ignore these messages, unless you want to take a lead in refactoring the code to work with later PHP versions. I will edit in a note, however, that if nobody updates the library, it will stop working in future, so may not be a good long-term bet if it doesn't look actively maintained.